# How to create a custom reporter with Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am sure I am missing something obvious here!

I have read the instructions here (https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Third-party-reporters), and have taken their code and added as a new node module (i.e. it is within `node_modules/my-reporter/reporter.js`). However, I can't seem to get mocha to load this reporter.

I have tried numerous variations …

```
mocha allTests.js -R ./node_modules/my-reporter/reporter.js

mocha allTests.js -R my-reporter
```

But nothing works :-(

I can successfully load my reporter within a JS file:

```
my_reporter = require('./node_modules/my-reporter/reporter.js')
console.log(my_reporter);
```

Has anyone got any hints?

Comment: Do you get an error or does it just go forth without using your reporter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that if mocha is installed globally (which I believe it almost always is), you have to install your reporter the same way.

If you don't want to publish the reporter as a public module, you can just:

```
npm pack
npm install /path/to/your/module.gz -g
```

I've tried putting the reporter everywhere else that would make sense, but was getting "invalid reporter" unless it was installed globally.

Comment: Thanks TPresley. I had to hunt for this info  for 2 hrs..will try a local installation of mocha later on to see how that pans out.

Comment: You can use `which` to find the path to a binary. Running `which mocha` in the terminal returns `/usr/local/bin/mocha` for me

Answer (score 9):

u should provide the reporter like this:

```
mocha allTests.js -R './node_modules/my-reporter/reporter'
```

You should not provide the .js file extension as that is the normal convention for including modules.